# How to use dplyr summarize to get the Ns of a group in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Company.Name    Rating1 Rating2 Rating3
CompanyA    NA 4.2  NA
CompanyB    1.2 1.2 1.5
CompanyA    1.4 NA  3.4
CompanyD    2.2 NA  4.3
CompanyC    1.9 1.7 2.4
CompanyB    NA  1.8 NA
CompanyA    4.2 3.2 NA
CompanyB    NA  2.1 4.4
```

What I'd like to do is create a new data frame of each unique company name in the first column; summarize for each unique company name the means of each rating and the number of complete ratings (number of ratings that are not NA), and do this with one function call.

I know with the dplyr package this function will get the means,

```
summarize(group_by(Data, Company.Name),
    Rating1_Avg = mean(Rating1, na.rm = TRUE), 
    Rating2_Avg = mean(Rating2, na.rm = TRUE), 
    Rating3_Avg = mean(Rating3, na.rm = TRUE) )
```

but how do I get the number of complete ratings?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the website's help section for formatting code when writing your next question.

Comment: How do you want to handle NAs when calculating the means? Do you want to ignore them or return NA?

Comment: @ulfelder From the OP's code, it looks like it should be removed `na.rm = TRUE`

Comment: Yes I want to ignore NAs. So I want the count to give me the number of "Rating1" a specific company received. so For example CompanyA has a count of 2 for "Rating1", since it has 2 complete ratings.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Company.Name) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(Avg=mean(., na.rm=TRUE), complete=sum(!is.na(.))))
```